# Me and my mom and dad moved to a older house since we have moved in we have had health problems

Tags: safety, mold, old-house

Me and my mom and dad have been having health problems since we have moved in our house in October , have brain fog and anxiety and my alleges and ashms and rashes and my mom and dad have been having heart problems and ever body has anxiety and moody , my mom and I have talk fast, and feel like we have ran a race, please let me know if you think our house is making us sick, we had to leave one over black mold, please if know what this please let me know

Comment: Do you have gas appliances or heat? Do you have a carbon monoxide detector?

Comment: I would suggest visiting a doctor to have your conditions diagnosed and asking about potential causes. Once you know what it is and what could be causing it, you can make a much more thorough investigation of your environment - home, work, school, etc. to determine which, if any, are contributing. While the house move is a major event common to all 3 of you, that may not be the only thing that's changed in your lives. TBH, even though the folks here are caring, they're not the ones to turn to for medical issues.

Comment: there is no way to guess what is actually causing your problems ... it may be the house or not be the house ... it could be stress caused by the new surroundings ... it could be something in the air in the neighborhood ... it could be low frequency sound from a factory ... the choices are endless

Comment: Have your house tested for methamphetamine, you might of moved into an old meth cook house.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have your new home inspected for excess dust, mold, CO, CO2 and any other pathogens. Most of these items would have been found with a good home inspection. Also, the heating system, exhaust vents, chimneys, any air filters, water lines and sewers need to be inspected. Areas of excess humidity and wet spots need to be addressed. There may be other problems but these should be looked at first.